# How to remove p tag from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to remove p tag from wordpress that automatically adds p tag in images.Also i center the images with wordpress so it becomes something like this

so i tried adding this code

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){
return preg_replace('/<p style=".*?">\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU',           '\1\2\3', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

This removes style from p tag and it become something like this

```
<p><img src=...><p>
```

Can anyone help me how to remove p from images only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content)
{    
    return preg_replace('/<p>(\s*)(<img .* \/>)(\s*)<\/p>/iU', '\2', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Or try to modify your own code:

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content)
{    
    $content = preg_replace('/<p style=".*?">\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU',           '\1\2\3', $content);
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}   
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

Answer (score 1):

using this hack you had remove P tag from your content please use this hack and let me know once this work fine.

```
remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');
remove_filter ('comment_text', 'wpautop');
```

Comment: i think this will remove all p tags from the content i can use wordpress default filter 'remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');' but this will remove p tags from text also

Comment: Moreover it will leave opening p tags with attributes untouched while removing their closing counterparts.  Use with caution.

Comment: use this filter to remove p tag `remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');
remove_filter ('comment_text', 'wpautop');`

Comment: this will remove p tags from my content too which i wrote as an article.