# Strip automatic P tags around images, videos, iframes in WordPress 4.9

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming, youtube-iframe-api

### THE ISSUE

I'm trying to size my YouTube video that I'm inserting and I got some working CSS to style it correctly, but the fact that WordPress keeps adding <P> tags around my video, image, and iframe tags is breaking my code. I'm only trying to remove paragraph tag wraps from elements (video/img/iframe) in blog content sections (not sidebars, widgets, footers, etc.)

#### CLIENT WEBSITE:

*This website is for a client so the code needs to be as unobtrusive as possible. For instance, a good solution would be a custom shortcode, or something that allows me to target the videos with CSS styling rules.*

Here is a blog post on the website in question:
http://ehepperle.com/in-progress/feelheal/11/how-to-create-125-px-ad-banner-gimp/

[image: [img]]

### MY SYSTEM

- **WordPress:** 4.9.6
- **Theme:** Storefront
- **Website:** http://ehepperle.com/in-progress/feelheal/11/how-to-create-125-px-ad-banner-gimp/

### MY CODE

Since this is specific to WordPress filters rather than general coding concepts, I haven't found a way to make a good demonstration example, but here are code snippets showing what I've tried:

#### functions.php - ver. 1

```
// Remove P Tags Around Images 
// From: http://justlearnwp.com/remove-p-tag-around-wordpress-images/
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

#### functions.php - ver. 2

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539888/remove-automatic-p-tag-in-wordpress#answer-44540531
function reformat_auto_p_tags($content) {
    $new_content = '';
    $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';
    $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';
    $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {
            $new_content .= $matches[1];
        } else {
            $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');

add_filter('the_content', 'reformat_auto_p_tags', 99);
add_filter('widget_text', 'reformat_auto_p_tags', 99);
```

### LINKS I REVIEWED BEFORE POSTING

I've tried solutions pieced together from these different possible solutions, all to no avail.

- From: [Remove automatic p tag in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539888/remove-automatic-p-tag-in-wordpress)
- http://justlearnwp.com/remove-p-tag-around-wordpress-images/
- [How to Remove P Tags Around Images in WordPress Posts From Source Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMPPPXVrYCs)
- https://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-remove-the-paragraph-tag-from-images-inside-the-wordpress-post-content/
- https://ahmadawais.com/remove-the-p-paragraph-tags-from-author-description-in-wordpress/
- https://firstsiteguide.com/stop-adding-paragraphs-automatically/#comment-424246
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop
- http://micahjon.com/2016/removing-wrapping-p-paragraph-tags-around-images-wordpress/
- [How to remove p tag from wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233096/how-to-remove-p-tag-from-wordpress)

### MY QUESTIONS

The following questions are actually multiple aspects of the same main question to gather the most complete understanding from various perspectives.

1. How can I remove <p> tags from iframes, video, and image tags in WordPress? The methods I've located from the past 2 years (and earlier) don't seem to work.
2. What is wrong with my code? Why are removing wpautop filters not working in my functions.php?
3. Did something change with WP version 4.8-4.9 that is making these filter hacks not work any more?

## UPDATE: 2018-09-05

I'm adding my complete functions.php file in case anyone can help identify something that is causing a conflict. I don't see any, but maybe you will see something I missed.

### functions.php (complete)

```php
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    //* Parent CSS
    wp_enqueue_style( 'storefront', 
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    //* Child CSS
    wp_enqueue_style( 'storefront-ehw-1', 
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', [ 'storefront' ] );
} );

/* Adds search box to top nav menu
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2 );
function add_search_box( $items, $args ) {
    $items .= '<li class="widget widget_search">' . get_search_form( false ) . '</li>';
    return $items;
}
*/

/* Hide categories from WordPress category widget
NOTE: 59 is the id of .Test-Posts category. This hides that from users.*/
function exclude_widget_categories($args){
    $exclude = "59";
    $args["exclude"] = $exclude;
    return $args;
}
add_filter("widget_categories_args","exclude_widget_categories");

/* Add Google fonts */
function wpb_add_google_fonts() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'wpb-google-fonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aguafina Script|Neucha|The Girl Next Door|Quintessential|Open Sans|Raleway', false ); 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_add_google_fonts' );


/**
 * Display the theme credit
 *
 * @since  1.0.0
 * @return void
 */
function storefront_credit() {
    ?>
    <div class="site-info">
        <?php echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'storefront_copyright_text', $content = 'Copyright &copy; ' . date( 'Y' ) . ' ' . get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) ); ?>
        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'storefront_credit_link', true ) ) { ?>

        <br />

        <?php echo '<a href="https://erichepperle.com" target="_blank" title="' . esc_attr__( 'Eric Hepperle Designs - Affordable eCommerce WordPress websites for small business', 'storefront-ehw-1' ) . '" rel="author">' . esc_html__( 'Designed by: Eric Hepperle Designs', 'storefront-ehw-1' ) . '</a>' ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- .site-info -->/*<?php
}


/* **** VARIOUS ATTEMPTS TO REMOVE P-TAGS FROM YOUTUBE VIDEO THUMBNAILS ****

// Remove P Tags Around Images 
// From: http://justlearnwp.com/remove-p-tag-around-wordpress-images/
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');

// Remove P Tags Around videos 
function filter_ptags_on_vids($content){
    return preg_replace('/<video>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/video>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_vids');

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539888/remove-automatic-p-tag-in-wordpress#answer-44540531
function reformat_auto_p_tags($content) {
    $new_content = '';
    $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';
    $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';
    $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {
            $new_content .= $matches[1];
        } else {
            $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');

add_filter('the_content', 'reformat_auto_p_tags', 99);
add_filter('widget_text', 'reformat_auto_p_tags', 99);

// ------------ FROM STACK OVERFLOW ------------------------
// 
// Remove p tags from images, scripts, and iframes.
function remove_some_ptags( $content ) {
$content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<script.*>*.<\/script>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe.*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_some_ptags' );

*/

// Add the filter to manage the p tags
add_filter( 'the_content', 'jb_remove_autop_for_image', 0 );

function jb_remove_autop_for_image( $content )
{
    global $post;

     // Here you can write condition as per your requirement.
     // i have added example for your idea
    if ( is_single() && $post->post_type == 'image' )
        remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
// Add the filter to manage the p tags
add_filter( 'the_content', 'jb_remove_autop_for_image', 0 );

function jb_remove_autop_for_image( $content )
{
    global $post;

     // Here you can write condition as per your requirement.
     // i have added example for your idea
    if ( is_single() && $post->post_type == 'image' )
        remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jagir. I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Did you check ?

Comment: Not yet. I'll try this week

Comment: Sorry I didn't get to this quickly. I checked today and found this does not work. I created a test post where I manually surrounded image <img> tags with `<p>` tags and inserted your code at the bottom of my functions.php file. Sadly, it did not strip P tags.

Comment: !!! This code broke two different websites (500 Error) using different themes from different companies !!! I was able to get the websites back up by deleting your code. By testing your code in the functions.php file with various theme and plugin you can identify what your code is conflicting with. `I advise users avoid this code as it has already broken two websites`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap embedded iframes, images, videos etc. in your own wrapper. WP then wouldn't add `<p>` tags. Use 'oembed_dataparse' filter.

```
// Wrap iframe for embedded video in <div> with custom class.
// Add class-modifier if aspect ratio is 4/3. 
function wrap_oembed_dataparse($return, $data, $url) {

    $mod = '';

    if  (   ( $data->type == 'video' ) &&
            ( isset($data->width) ) && ( isset($data->height) ) &&
            ( round($data->height/$data->width, 2) == round( 3/4, 2) )
        )
    {
        $mod = 'embed-responsive--4-3';
    }

    return '<div class="embed-responsive ' . $mod . '">' . $return . '</div>';
}

add_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', 'wrap_oembed_dataparse', 99, 4 );
```

Comment: To make filter work you might have to clear oEmbed post meta cache. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203537/how-can-i-clear-oembed-caches-for-youtube-on-posts-as-they-are-loaded

Answer (score 0):

This Vanilla-JS-function searches for all iframes, and moves them outside of their parents:

```
moveIframesOutOfPtags() {
  let iframes = document.querySelectorAll( 'iframe' );

  let before = "<div class="iframe-container">";
  let after = "</div>";

  Object.entries( iframes ).forEach( entry => {
    let value = entry[1];

    if( value.parentNode.nodeName === 'P' || value.parentNode.nodeName === 'p' ){
      value.parentNode.outerHTML = before + value.parentNode.innerHTML + after;
    }
  });
}
```

Tested and works.

I'm using it in a Vue-app, so I've put it in the mounted section. If you're not using vue, then you would have to put the function inside a `<script` and run it inside some `window.onload(() => { ... });`

Depending on how you control the scripts on your page, then you should put it there, enqueued in your functions-file (good) or just straight up in the footer (bad).

**Bonus info**

I've also added a container-div (`.iframe-container`) to put the iframe into. By using [this method](https://jameshfisher.com/2017/08/30/how-do-i-make-a-full-width-iframe/) then you can add these styles and then scale the iframe to fill 100% width, an keeping a set aspect ratio%.

Answer (score -1):

Here I am sending the code for removing p tag From Images scripts and iframes.

```
// Remove p tags from images, scripts, and iframes.
function remove_some_ptags( $content ) {
$content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<script.*>*.<\/script>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe.*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_some_ptags' );
```

Kindly check.

Comment: I tested the code you provided after clearing cache and history for all time and it still did not work. The code looks like it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Remember to attribute [where you got this from](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/239452/removing-p-tags-around-img-iframes-and-also-scripts) .